How to Replace values within an object that is in an array?
The problem I am facing is that I am trying to replace the text and date with an edit function. I got it working to a point where it is replacing the text via the DOM, but when the page refreshes the edited version resets to its old values. I think I know why, it is because the values within the object that is in the array need to stay changed and it is not, which I  do not think I am doing correctly.
I think maybe using a map, which could create a new array and render the updated array on the DOM.
Please review the code below:
let Editedmodal = document.querySelector("#edit-modal");
let editBtn = document.querySelector(".edit");

function editTask(id) {
  let taskIndex = taskArray.findIndex((task) => task.id === id);
  let taskElement = document.querySelector(`.task-to-do[data-id="${id}"]`);

  let Editedmodal = document.querySelector("#edit-modal");


  EditedInputTask.value = taskArray[taskIndex].task;
  EditedInputDate.value = taskArray[taskIndex].date;

  Editedmodal.style.display = "grid";
  /*Submit Edited task Form*/
  EditedsubmitForm.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();
    /*Form Validaion*/
    if (!EditedInputTask.value) {
      EditedInputNoTask.style.display = "block";
      EditedInputTask.style.marginTop = "-1em";
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        EditedInputNoTask.style.display = "none";
        EditedInputTask.style.marginTop = "0";
      }, 3000);
    }

    if (!EditedInputDate.value) {
      EditedInputNoDate.style.display = "block";
      EditedInputDate.style.marginTop = "-1em";

      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        EditedInputNoDate.style.display = "none";
        EditedInputDate.style.marginTop = "0";
      }, 3000);
    } else {
      Editedmodal.style.display = "none";
      EditedInputTask.value = "";
      EditedInputDate.value = "";
      taskArray[taskIndex].task = taskObjEdited;
      taskArray[taskObjEdited.task] = DateStore;
    }

    taskArray[taskIndex].task = EditedInputTask.value;
    taskArray[taskIndex].date = EditedInputDate.value;

    taskElement.querySelector("#list-item-date").textContent = `Due: ${taskArray[taskIndex].date}`;
    taskElement.querySelector("#list-item-task").textContent = taskArray[taskIndex].task;

  });

function storeTaskArrayLocally() {
  localStorage.setItem("taskLocalstorage", JSON.stringify(taskArray));
}

function initializeTaskAraryFromLocalStoraege() {
  const storedTask = localStorage.getItem("taskLocalstorage");

  if (storedTask) {
    taskArray = JSON.parse(storedTask);
    renderTask();
  }
}


Wait, I'm not sure that I understand, you change some DOM element and when you refresh page, it returns to normal like you didn't change anything? If that's so, it is quite normal. Is there any mechanism that would remember what you changed so that on page refresh it apply same change or fill DOM elements with changed values? If there is none, why do you think it would stay changed after page refresh?

I do have a function that stores the array in a local storage. you can take a look at the project in my GitHub account
https://github.com/SheldonAldridge/To_Do_App_-Vanilla-/blob/main/resources/js/main.js

yeah but you are not calling that function storeTaskArrayLocally anywhere in your code or initializeTaskAraryFromLocalStoraege for that matter. If you do, then please edit your question and provide all relevant code including the HTML to demostrate the problem. Use the snippet provided by SO, no external links or images. Also make sure you are naming/calling functions with their correct names

taskObjEdited is not defined anywhere in your original code. Look at your editTask function

taskArray[taskObjEdited.task] = DateStore; this also looks like a typo or an unnecessary line

When you change a task in the task array you need to store the array in localStorage again:
  // change the task in the array
  taskArray[taskIndex].task = EditedInputTask.value;
  taskArray[taskIndex].date = EditedInputDate.value;
  // store the task array in localStorage
  storeTaskArrayLocally();


Thank you, this is storing the new object values.
